# Retrieving array item within code quotation

Tags: f#, metaprogramming

As part of a hobby project, I would like to dynamically create a function that, when supplied an array of floats, it can then perform some arithmetic using the array elements and return a result.

Note that the function will have to be created at runtime.

I *believe* this can be done by constructing a lambda expression using the `FSharp.Quotations.Expr` module.

Taking the following simple example:

```
fun (arr: float array) -> 2.0 * arr.[0]
```

I can re-create this using a code quotation such as:

```
<@ fun (arr: float array) -> 2.0 * arr.[0] @>
```

Printing this to the console yields:

```
Lambda (arr,
        Call (None, op_Multiply,
              [Value (2.0), Call (None, GetArray, [arr, Value (0)])]))
```

I can see that the `GetArray` referred to is that located `FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.GetArray`.

My question is... **How can I create `Call (None, GetArray, [arr, Value (0)])` at runtime?**

---

My (embarassing) attempt so far is:

```
open System
open FSharp.Quotations

let arr = Var("arr", typeof<float array>, false)

let getArray = FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.IntrinsicFunctions.GetArray.GetType().GetMethods().[0]

Expr.Lambda(arr, Expr.Call(getArray, [Expr.Var(arr); Expr.Value(0)]))
```

This yields the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Type mismatch when building 'args': invalid parameter for a method or indexer property. Expected 'System.Object[]', but received type 'System.Double[]'.

Given that `GetArray` looks to be a generic function, it's not clear to me why this is happening.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something rather fundamental here!

Thank you for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to obtain the `MethodInfo` for `GetArray` itself, which requires reflection. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do this, but the following seems to work:

```ml
let arr = Var("arr", typeof<float array>, false)
let getArray =
    let asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("FSharp.Core")
    let typ = asm.DefinedTypes |> Seq.find (fun typ -> typ.Name = "IntrinsicFunctions")
    let getArrayGeneric = typ.GetMethod("GetArray")
    getArrayGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(typeof<double>)
let expr = Expr.Lambda(arr, Expr.Call(getArray, [Expr.Var(arr); Expr.Value(0)]))
printfn "%A" expr   // Lambda (arr, Call (None, GetArray, [arr, Value (0)]))
```

This finds the generic `GetArray` method inside the `FSharp.Core` assembly, and then instantiates it with `double` to obtain a `MethodInfo` for `GetArray<double>`, which is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look... However, the proposed change above is giving a different exception:
`The member is non-static (instance), but no receiver object was supplied Arg_ParamName_Name`.

Note that I'm using `....GetMethods().[0]` as an attempt to get the `Invoke(...)` method. However, I'm now wondering if this is a non-static member hence the exception?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing the same thing and looking into it. Expressions are finicky. :) Will update the answer if I figure it out.

Comment: I have something that seems to work and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for that @brianberns. Given my knowledge, I wouldn't have thought to get the MethodInfo for GetArray using your approach above.

What you've provided allows me to recreate that quotation at runtime which is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer solves the problem perfectly fine. I can think of one slight simplification, which would be to extract the `GetArray` method info from a minimal quotation, so that you do not have to worry about finding the method manually using reflection.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let arr = Var("arr", typeof<float array>, false)
let getArray<'T> = match <@ ([||] : 'T[]).[0] @> with Patterns.Call(_, mi, _) -> mi | _ -> failwith "Array access was not Call"
let expr = Expr.Lambda(arr, Expr.Call(getArray<float>, [Expr.Var(arr); Expr.Value(0)]))
printfn "%A" expr
```

This may be a bit more future proof in case the method moved, but it still only works if the array access is exposed as a method call.

Maybe an even more interesting approach is to use quotation splicing, which lets you separate the bit that cosntructs the array access into a function, but keep that written as a quotation:

```
let arr = Var("arr", typeof<float array>, false)

let getArray (e:Expr<'T[]>) (a:Expr<int>) = 
  <@ (%e).[%a] @>

let expr = 
  Expr.Lambda(arr, 
    getArray (Expr.Cast<float array>(Expr.Var(arr))) 
      (Expr.Cast<int>(Expr.Value(0))))

printfn "%A" expr
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas... I agree those are both really elegant alternatives! In particular, your second approach is particularly impressive, avoiding the need for reflection at all (if I'm understanding it correctly?). This has definitely been a useful insight into working with quotations.

Comment: Yes, the second approach avoids the need for reflection - the only tricky thing there is that you need to have the type of the array as a static type (so that you can call `getArray` with the right type argument. If this was a runtime information, it does not work (you could make it work but through different reflection hacks).

Comment: Understood. And thank you for confirming!

Comment: Just to say... I used that second approach to create quotation splicers for simple addition and multiplication operations as well. Worked like a charm! ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/richfgmills/0348570819b90ee4f7456b526a06c6ab)).

Comment: @RMills330 Nice!